# Transaction doesn't work in Yii

Tags: mysql, activerecord, transactions, yii

this is my code:

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
            try {
                $tModel->save();
                $activationLink = new ActivationLink;
                $activationLink->User_id = $tModel->id;
                $activationLink->hash1   = User::generateHashCode(100);
                $activationLink->hash2   = User::generateHashCode();
                $activationLink->hash3   = User::generateHashCode();
                $activationLink->time    = time();
                $activationLink->save();                    
                User::sendActivatonLink($tModel->mail,$activationLink->id, $activationLink->hash1, $activationLink->hash2, $activationLink->hash3);
                $transaction->commit();
                $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $tModel->id));
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $transaction->rollback();
                Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', "{$e->getMessage()}");
                $this->refresh();
            }
```

`$tModel` saved but `$activationLink` doesn't so it should rolled back. but it didn't ,why?

Comment: You are not committing your changes as far as I can see (but then I don't know PHP or Yii)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yii save() does not throw an exception, when just the validation fails. Thus you have to check the result of save() yourself:

```
if (!$model->save())
   $transaction->rollback();

//or:

if (!$model->save())
   throw new Exception("This will trigger my catch statement block");
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check your mysql engine I think you are not using innodb. To execute transaction we must use innodb. Let me know your table type/engine.

OR 
You also need to add in your code to understand error in log.

throw new Exception($e);