# Yii transaction doen't roll back

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii, transactions

Yii transaction doesn't roll back in the below sample code and records saved in DB:

```
        $transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
        $mode_1 = new Orders;
        $mode_1->id_order = 3333;
        $mode_1->AWB = 3333;
        $mode_2 = new Orders;
        $mode_2->id_order = 4444;
        $mode_2->AWB = 4444;
        $mode_2->save();
        $mode_1->save();
    $transaction->rollback();
```

any Idea? .. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Transaction doesn't work in Yii](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789965/transaction-doesnt-work-in-yii)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure that the storage engine for your tables is InnoDB. I believe it is the only transaction-safe engine available by default. More on available engines in the [mysql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-engines.html)

Comment: Yes it is working perfectly now. I changed my table engine from MyISAM to InnoDB .. thank you for your advice :)

Comment: You saved me too. Working like Charm

Answer (score 13):

The right way to use transactions is to use them with the try-catch construction. In your example I think that the problem comes because you didn't do the commit ($transaction->commit()).

```
$transaction = Yii::app()->db->beginTransaction();
try {
    if (!$model->save()) {
        throw new Exception('Model cannot be saved.');
    }
    if (!$anothermodel->save()) {
        throw new Exception('Anothermodel cannot be saved.');
    }

    $transaction->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
}
```

**EDIT:** $model->save() doesn't throw Exception, so you need to throw it!

Comment: Actually putting the try-catch doesn't effect or change anything.

Comment: But in this case you can't have the save model, commit transaction and rollback transaction in the same time. And it's strange to successfully save the data to DB and after data to rollback the transaction.

Comment: Though this answer might not have solved your question, this answer is however teaching the correct way of doing a transaction. That's a reason for an up vote right there!